How do I find the supremum and infimum of $\left\{x\in\mathbb{R} \setminus 0: \frac{2x}{3}-\frac{x^2-3}{2x} + 0.5 < \frac{x}{6} \right\}$?
$A=\{x \in \mathbb{R}: \frac{2x}{3}-\frac{x^2-3}{2x} + 0.5 < \frac{x}{6}, x \neq 0\}$
I tried simplifying this inequality and got $x+3<0$, which is $x<-3$. But that means that either $x>0$ and $x<-3$ or $x<0$ and $x<-3$. The first case can be disregarded (I think) because it is not bounded on either sides, so that leaves us with the second case ($x<0$, $x<-3$), where $0$ is the supremum, but I don't know how to find the infimum.

HINT
To start with, let us solve the corresponding inequality which defines $A$
\begin{align*}
\frac{2x}{3} - \frac{x^{2} - 3}{2x} + \frac{1}{2} < \frac{x}{6} & \Longleftrightarrow 4x - \frac{3x^{2} - 9}{x} + 3 < x\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow 3x - \frac{3x^{2} - 9}{x} + 3 < 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \frac{3x + 9}{x} < 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \frac{x + 3}{x} < 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow -3 < x < 0
\end{align*}
Can you take it from here?

Amogh Kulkarni: Notice here the last $\iff$, which differs from your result. The point to remember is that when you multiply by $x$ to get rid of the denominator, the inequality may change direction depending on the sign of $x$. So you should split up into cases before this point

Thank you so much! The sign of x is what I was not being careful about. Again, thanks! This was extremely helpful!
